# How KnockOut works when it is used to populate a combo

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

i got a piece of code regarding KnockOut to populate dropdown using jquery too.
i am not at all familiar with KnockOut so i am now being able to understand it how it works.

so please tell me the meaning of KnockOut related code.
here is full code

```
<p>
    Your country:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" runat="server" data-bind="options: countryModel.countries, optionsValue: 'CountryID', optionsText: 'CountryName', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</p>
<input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click: addCountry" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function DropDownModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.countries = ko.observableArray();
        self.addCountry = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "DropDownSolution.aspx/GetCountries",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    self.countries(data.d);
                }
            });
        };
    }
    var countryModel = new DropDownModel()
    ko.applyBindings(countryModel);
</script>

    WebMethod]
    public static List<Country> GetCountries()
    {
        List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
        countries.Add(new Country { CountryID = "1", CountryName = "India" });
        countries.Add(new Country { CountryID = "2", CountryName = "Singapore" });
        countries.Add(new Country { CountryID = "3", CountryName = "Malaysia" });
        return countries;
    }
```

so my concern is i am not able to understand KnockOut related code.

```
ko.applyBindings(countryModel);
```

**what is ko?**

```
var self = this;
self.countries = ko.observableArray();
self = this means what....so self hold which reference?

self.countries = ko.observableArray();
what is ko and how ko comes?
what is observableArray() & what is does?
```

it seems that **self.addCountry = function () {** addCountry fire automatically when
   DropDownModel() function will be invoked. how a function can be call automatically?

how KnockOut can populate dropdown....how it will understand how to populate a dropdown.

please guide me in detail. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is ko?

`ko` is the global knockout object. It is added when you include the `knockout.js` script. It is like the `$` variable for jquery.

> it seems that self.addCountry = function () { addCountry fire automatically when DropDownModel() function will be invoked. how a function can be call automatically?

This function is not called automatically. Instead it has been connected to the add button with the following.

```
<input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click: addCountry" />
```

That binds the `addCountry` method to the `click` handler of the button input.

> how KnockOut can populate dropdown....how it will understand how to populate a dropdown.

The dropdown is populated using the `options` binding as seen in the following piece of code from your example.

```
// Note that I removed some of the other attributes so that it is 
// easier to see the knockout only attributes.
<asp:DropDownList data-bind="options: countryModel.countries, optionsValue: 'CountryID', optionsText: 'CountryName', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You can find the documentation for each `options` specific binding value [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).

You can also find all of knockout's documentation at [knockoutjs.com](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: can u plzz tell me what is the advantage of knockout.js....why people would use it. instead of using knockout.js we can bind data using jquery template. so why some one use knockout.js instead of jquery template.

Comment: Have a look at their webpage, http://knockoutjs.com/, to see the key points they make for why you would use it. For me, knockoutjs makes it much easier to make interactive GUIs.

Comment: I am not familiar with jquery template so I cannot answer that question.